# How do I keep a server button from refreshing an ASPX View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASPX view in my MVC application that has a FileSelector, a label, and a button that is supposed to put the FileSelector's selected file name and size into the label (this is for testing purposes; the final version will send the FileSelector's FileBytes byte array to an SQL Server database).  Hoewver, when I press the button, the page refreshes, and the label is unchanged.

Here is the view code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<script runat="server" language="C#">
    void btnLoad_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] B = FileSelector.FileBytes;
        lblStatus.Text = "File \"" + FileSelector.FileName + "\" has size " + B.Length;
    }
</script>
<head runat="server">
    <title>ABMC - Add Photo (ASPX version) </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <form runat="server">
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileSelector" runat="server" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="btnLoad" Text="Load" runat="server" OnClick="btnLoad_Click" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server">No file selected yet</asp:Label>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I select a file and then click on the "Load" button, the page refreshes, and the label still reads, "No file selected yet."

I did manage to get this to work (sort of) by using a separate ASPX form (with the code in a separate .aspx.cs file) rather than an MVC View, but I have to pass a Model back to the page that called this page, so I would prefer doing this in a View.

Comment: If this is an MVC project then you would not be able to access server controls the way you described: `<form runat="server">`, `<asp:FileUpload>`. Nor will you be able to execture the `btnLoad_Click` method. It seems to me that this is a WebForms project

Comment: If this was a webforms project you would remove `runat="server"` or catch it in JQuery `$("#btnLoad").click(function(){ return false })`

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with this as a separate View, but I did get it to work as a hybrid MVC/WebForms project (it's pretty much the only way I could get the file selector to be able to read a file from the client without JavaScript complaining).

As for "passing the model back to the calling page," **THWACK** - I don't need to pass the Model - just to call the View through Request.QueryString with the parameters appended as if it was a URL.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add "return false" to the btnLoad_Click call. Try using return btnLoad_Click and returning false from that function.